# Unable to mix shaders with ambient occlusion in cycles

Tags: shaders, ambient-occlusion

Following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/7F6jzEybPKU?t=200) I'm somehow not able to mix my *bsdf* shaders. It's one or another, though I want the snow scattered on the magenta.

### What I have:
[image: pic]
[image: pic]
What I want:
[image: pic]
[image]
[snow texture](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475156366402-ffdc49dd371f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=kelly-sikkema-dsNSBoNGCRs-unsplash.jpg)

## TLDR; Render engine, was set to evee instead of cycles

See chris' answer

Comment: I am not really sure, it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't check "ambient occlusion" here:

[image]

If you also move the black slider of your colorramp a bit more to the right....you get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris. I'm using cycles :/

Comment: well...please add this info to your question. And if you upload a file...it should have set the render engine you want to use. Yours was set to EEVEE.

Comment: That was the problem. The engine was set to `eevee`. Would never have checked, I never even used eevee before.